# JPA (Eclipselink) @OneToMany misses some entrys

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I got 2 Entities

Customer.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer"; fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Invoice> invoice;
}
```

and

Invoice.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Invoice")
public class Invoice {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer")
    private Customer customer;
    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private double price;
}
```

They are both mapped in the persistence.xml.

So:

```
System.out.println(customer);
```

for a specific customer gives me 30 Invoice entrys, but I got 33 in the Database.

I use org.eclipse.persistence.jpa 2.5.0 and persistence-api 1.0.2

I appreciate every hint/solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This mapping makes no sense. How can the customer be the ID of Invoice, since theveral invoices have the same customer? An ID is supposed to be unique.

Comment: The PK in the Database consists of multiple Columns. Do I have to use EmbeddedId? How should the ManyToOne and JoinColumn look then? Thanks

Comment: Show us the complete mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply 
I found the problem/answer.

After just trying @EmbeddedId I had to declare the @JoinColumn insertable and updatable false.

The right mapping for the Invoice.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Invoice")
public class Invoice {
    @EmbeddedId
    private InvoiceId invoiceId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Customer customer;
    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private double price;
}

@Embeddable
class InvoiceId implements Serializable {
    //Composite PK
    @Column(name = "customerId")
    private int customerId;
    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date;
}
```